# Content Control getting nested in word

Tags: office-js, word-addins, word-web-addins

I created a project using Office js and word Api 1.3,which loads the Ooxml data of the content controls stored in database into the document.
i am facing an issue while loading the Ooxml data which has content controls into document

for example: if i am loading 3 content controls into the document

my requirement is to load content controls one after another in the document

[image: Requirement]

but it loads first content control and inside that second content control and inside that third content control

[image: Result]

Code used to store the Ooxml data of the content controls into Database:

```js
// Create a proxy object for the ConentControl body.
var ConentControl = context.document.contentControls.getByTag('FirstControl').getFirst();

// Queue a commmand to get the OOXML contents of the body.
var OOXML = ConentControl.getOoxml();
```

i am storing this OOXML in Database as an xml field

Code used to retrieve

```js
function GetTemplateData() {

    var apiurl = 'Service Url'

    $.ajax({
        url: apiurl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        //contentType: 'application/json',
        //data: JSON.stringify(searchDetails),
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                var ControlName = element.ControlName;
                var ControlContent = element.ContentData;
                InsertOoxml(ControlName, ControlContent);
             });
         },
        error: function (d) {
            write("Error please try again");
        }
    });
}

function InsertOoxml(ControlName, ControlContent) {
    Word.run(function (context) {

        // Create a proxy object for the content controls collection that contains a specific tag.
        currentOOXML = ControlContent;
        if (currentOOXML != "" && currentOOXML != null) {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.
            var DocBody = context.document.body;

            // Queue a commmand to insert OOXML in to the beginning of the body.
            DocBody.insertOoxml(currentOOXML, Word.InsertLocation.end);

            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
            // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync().then(function () {

                // Tell the user we succeeded and then clear the message after a 2 second delay
                report.innerText = "Section Loaded succeeded!";
                setTimeout(function () {
                    report.innerText = "";
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
        else {
            return context.sync().then(function () {

                // Tell the user we succeeded and then clear the message after a 2 second delay
                report.innerText = 'Data not available for the control in Database.';
                setTimeout(function () {
                    report.innerText = "";
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
    })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You're code is calling `context.sync` inside a loop. That should usually be avoided. I don't if it will fix your symptoms, but could you try just having the queue `insertOoxml` line in the loop, and then have a single `context.sync` after the loop completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly inserting a content control, try to first insert a paragraph and then insert the content control.

Here is the code:

```js
var contentControls = context.document.body.insertParagraph("text",Word.InsertLocation.end);
contentControls.insertOoxml(currentOOXML, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
```

Hope this helps!!!