# Inserting content control in word causing nesting

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I am working on an add-in which allows a user to select an image from the taskpane to insert into a Word document. In order to make it easier to find any images added this way and refresh to get the latest version I am inserting images (and text) into a content control with a unique tag.

```
const range = context.document.getSelection();
const paragraph = range.insertParagraph('', 'After');
const image = paragraph.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(base64Image, 'End');
paragraph.insertBreak(Word.BreakType.line, Word.InsertLocation.after)
    
const captionText = `${docTitle}`;
const caption = paragraph.insertText(captionText, Word.InsertLocation.end);

await context.sync();

const contentControl = paragraph.insertContentControl();
 contentControl.set({
   title: docTitle,
   tag: referenceToken,
   appearance: Word.ContentControlAppearance.boundingBox
 });
```

Currently everything is working fine. I can insert my image and text, find the control(s) later to update as needed.

However, I noticed that if I insert an image in this way, and then select another image to add, the second content control ends up nested in the first one.

How can I make sure that the current selection is not in a content control, and if it is move it to the line right after the control?
An example of someone else with this problem is here: [Content Control getting nested in word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974830/content-control-getting-nested-in-word), but the comment there did not help in my case, since that is how I am inserting currently.